# Is my upgrade failing if the screen appears to hang

Tags: upgrade, error

We're on 4.7.3 on Drupal 7, and are being affected by some bugs that affect contributions made on behalf of an organisation and paid for by paypal.

When I attempt the upgrade to 4.7.5, the upgrade script says it has updated to 4.7.4 without problems, but then hangs on Begin upgrade to 4.7.5 message

See: [image: Error]

I left it for 5 minutes (the php max runtime was set to 3 minutes) and then hit refresh, it emptied - no text or progress.  Re-opening the upgrade script then says it failed the integrity check. I've rolled back to a backup for now.

There is no error in the HTTP error log, nothing seems to have run out of memory.

I'd be grateful for any help in how to set about diagnosing this issue!

Comment: Hi Robin. we have nursed upgrades through that have taken hours. Could you retry but leave the upgrade running for a lot longer? If you need to it can be helpful to copy the url and paste in a new window and you may see progress on that screen. Also checking in the civicrm_domain table will show you were it is at. But it may be that patience is the issue here.

Comment: Thank you @petednz-fuzion I think you are right - using the SQL command SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST I can see it is in fact whirring away doing a number of database structural changes, which is necessitating some very large tables to be copied to temporary tables. I will leave it overnight and cross everything!

Comment: k - great to hear. i rewrote the above as an answer that might help others but good that you added your own ;-)

Comment: i tried to find a Title for this that might be more generically useful. by all means change it again if you can improve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some upgrades can take a long time and do not die just because the screen isn't showing progress.

Sometimes you can better see how things are going by copying the url and pasting in a new window and you may see progress on the new screen.

Also you can check in the civicrm_domain table which will show you where it is at.

Patience is often the issue here.

And as Robin added "using the SQL command SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST I can see it is in fact whirring away doing a number of database structural changes, which is necessitating some very large tables to be copied to temporary tables"

Comment: I followed you process here but not showing any activity for the above command. Result:Id     | User             | Host      | db                  | Command | Time | State | Info                  |
+--------+------------------+-----------+---------------------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+
| 799758 | db_user | localhost | _newjoomla3x | Query   |    0 | NULL  | SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST

Comment: Also, MYTOP doesn't show any activity.                                                                                    

MySQL on localhost (5.5.48-cll)                                                                                                                                up 25+21:38:27 [15:01:57]
 Queries: 440.0  qps:    0 Slow:     0.0         Se/In/Up/De(%):    2585933/00/00/00 
             qps now:    0 Slow qps: 0.0  Threads:    1 (   1/  35) 00/00/00/00 
 Key Efficiency: 100.0%  Bps in/out:   0.0/  0.9   Now in/out:   8.3/ 1.7k

Comment: Id      User         Host/IP         DB      Time    Cmd Query or State                                                                                                           
      --      ----         -------         --      ----    --- ----------                                                                                                               
  799853 alcohol_a       localhost alcohol_ne         0  Query show full processlist

Comment: hi . can't comment as that was a suggestion by Robin.

Answer (score 4):

Answer was patience - upgrade took 45 minutes.